# TextChanged event on textbox in dynamically added user control not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am dynamically adding a number of user controls, which have a textbox. When the text in the textbox is changed, I am trying to fire an event.

My code is as such:

**Default.aspx:**

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlControls" runat="server"/>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyControl control = (MyControl)LoadControl("Controls/MyControl.ascx");
    control.NameField = "Test Name";
    pnlControls.Controls.Add(control);
}
```

**MyControl.ascx**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNameField" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtNameField_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>
```

**MyControl.ascx.cs**

```
public string NameField;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostback)
    {
        txtNameField.Text = NameField;
    }
}

protected void txtNameField_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NameField = txtNameField.Text;
}
```

This is a simplified version of the code, which contains all relevant parts that are necessary to make the functionality work as required (as far as I know)

However, the `txtNameField_TextChanged` function is never executed. How can I make the function execute when the `txtNameField` text is changed?

Comment: You mean NameField dont have value if you change text?

Comment: No, I mean that the `txtNameField_TextChanged` function is never called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to assign an `ID` to the `UserControl`:

```
MyControl control = (MyControl)LoadControl("Controls/MyControl.ascx");
control.ID = "MyUserControl";
control.NameField = "Test Name";
pnlControls.Controls.Add(control);
```

Controls must have the same ID at postback to be able to fire events or to load their viewstate.

As an aside, you don't need to assign `txtNameField.Text` to your field in the event. Just use a property that gets/sets `txtNameField.Text`. Then you have always the correct value and it's also retained across postbacks automatically.

So instead of this:

```
public string NameField;

protected void txtNameField_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NameField = txtNameField.Text;
}
```

This:

```
public string NameField 
{
    get
    {
        return txtNameField.Text;
    }
    // maybe you want to make it public
    private set 
    {
        txtNameField.Text = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add txtNameField to your textChanged-Event.

MyControl:

```
this.TextChanged += new EventHandler(txtNameField_TextChanged);
```

At least I think that is what you are trying to do, because I can't see this Line anywhere in your code.

Comment: How binding an event handler programatically will help? OP is already binding it declaratively `OnTextChanged="txtNameField_TextChanged"`

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that somewhere the binding of your click event is getting lost. Please try to add your control dynamically earlier than the `Page_Load`, the best place to do it is in `Page_Init` where other controls are as well getting initialized. (at that point all other controls in your page are actually initialized)

Please check the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) where it is clearly indicated that dynamic controls should be added during the preinit stage. And [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9ecy7tf(v=vs.110).aspx) is a link to the `LoadControl` method you are using where the control is as well added dynamically in the init stage in the code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try & test with debugger attached.


I copied your code & executed, for me "OnTextChanged" event is firing.
Even I have placed the textbox inside user control which i am loading proframmatically.